How do I access a MATLAB UI function in another .m file?
I am attempting to declutter my MATLAB app code by separating some of the initialization into separate .m files. For this I have set up various files for each type of component (e.g. a file for buttons, graph, etc.). I am attempting to access a function in my master initialize file from the file for buttons. My code goes as follows in the buttons .m file goes as follow:
classdef buttons < handle
    methods
        %initializes the UI
        function buttonCreate(app)
           
            %Create file load 1
            app.fileload1 = uibutton(app.gridLayout, 'push');
            app.fileload1.FontSize = 36;
            app.fileload1.Layout.Row = [8 9];
            app.fileload1.Layout.Column = 1;
            app.fileload1.Text = 'Load 1';

            %proceeds to create the rest of the buttons
        end
    end
end

Now I attempt to access the buttonCreate() function in my master initialize file initialize.m:
classdef initialize < handle
    properties 
        fig
        gridLayout
        axes

        fileload1
    end
    methods
        %initializes the UI
        function init(app)
            %create canvas
            import buttons.*;
            fig = uifigure;
            fig.Position = [100 100 1920 1080];
            movegui(fig,'center');
            fig.Name = "Audio Editor";

            %Create grid layout
            gridLayout = uigridlayout(fig);
            gridLayout.ColumnWidth = {'1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x'};
            gridLayout.RowHeight = {'1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x'};

            buttonCreate(app);

        end
    end
    %code for calling and deleting
    methods
        %calls code to create canvas upon app start
        function app = initialize
            init(app)
        end
        %removes the app and deletes app.fig
        function delete(app)
            delete(app.fig);
        end
    end
end

Error in initialize/init (line 41)
            buttonCreate(app);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error in initialize (line 54)
            init(app)
            ^^^^^^^^^

This resulted in the UIFigure still being created, but with no button and the terminal giving the error given above.

It’s a method of a class. You need to create an object of that class and then call the object’s method. In MATLAB, functions don’t need to be methods of a class. You can make regular old functions. It’s not Java.

Seems like you're doing some sort of combination of two distinct things:

Use a simple function, which can be in its own .m file or one of the methods of your main class:

% in your initialise class constructor you still have
buttonCreate(app);

% In buttonCreate.m
function buttonCreate(app)           
    % Create file load 1
    app.fileload1 = uibutton(app.gridLayout, 'push');
    app.fileload1.FontSize = 36;
    app.fileload1.Layout.Row = [8 9];
    % ...
end


Use a class to hold references to all of your buttons, in which case the objects you create would be properties of that class, rather than the main app object:

% in your initialise class constructor you create a buttons
% object and assign it to the buttons property.
% The buttons don't need to know anything about the app, just
% the target grid layout to parent the buttons
app.buttons = buttons( app.gridLayout );

% In buttons.m
classdef buttons < handle
    properties
      fileload1
    end
    methods
        function obj = buttons( grid )           
            % Create file load 1
            obj.fileload1 = uibutton(grid, 'push');
            obj.fileload1.FontSize = 36;
            obj.fileload1.Layout.Row = [8 9];
            % ...
        end
    end
end


Thank you for the response, your solution #2 is more inline with what I'm trying to do, but when I use that solution, I get the error:
Error in initialize/init (line 39)
app.buttons = buttons( app.gridLayout );
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error in initialize (line 52)
init(app)
^^^^^^^^^

That isn't the descriptive bit of the error message, what's the full error message with the cause description?

Sorry about that, heres the full error, >> initialize
Error using uibutton (line 55)
'Parent' must be a parent component, such as a uifigure object.
Error in buttons (line 9)
obj.fileload1 = uibutton(grid, 'push');
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error in initialize/init (line 39)
app.buttons = buttons( app.gridLayout );
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error in initialize (line 52)
init(app)
^^^^^^^^^

I just got it to work, thank you so much!
